# How to type react-redux's useSelector?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Component, where do i call my LoaderStore:

```
const loaderStore = useSelector((state: any) => state.loader);
```

Loader reducer:

```
interface IState {
  isLoading: boolean;
  state: States;
  error: string | null;
}

const initialState: IState = {
  isLoading: false,
  state: States.init,
  error: null
};
```

But if export my `IState` interface in a component, then use it as:

```
const loaderStore = useSelector((state: IState) => state.loader);
```

Then i'm getting a following error:

```
TS2339: Property 'loader' does not exist on type 'IState'.
```

I want to point `const loaderStore` to a Loader main initialState, how can i type it correctly?

Comment: Could you tell us, what is `State` in `IState` interface,

Comment: Nothing, i just have a single `IState` interface. Guess i have to create another interface and nest it inside it?

Comment: As your code show, you have `state: States;` in `IState` interface. so `Sates` should also be an interface. I just want to know structure of `States` interface.

Comment: I think you want to access state.state.loader :D

Comment: @MujiburrehmanAnsari `States` - it's enum, not related to `state.loader`

Comment: so, from `const loaderStore = useSelector((state: IState) => state.loader);` What I can see is that `state` parameter is what you need. Just print it on console and check it is your `initialState` or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just needed to create a root interface for the root state:

```
export interface RootState {
  user: UserState;
  loader: LoaderState;
}
```

Where `UserState` and `LoaderState` are the actual interfaces for the state.

Comment: This solution led me in the right direction.

Note, you can also achieve something similar using something like this...

Where you use combine your reducers, i.e. perhaps you have something like

`export const rootReducer = combineReducers(` etc...

Then you can do the following to define your interface of the combined states.

`export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>`